# PyQt5 open new window on js window.open with properties

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I need to open a new window on click when there is window.open in html view...
it does open as per my code. But when there is window.open with properties then it opens new window once and then it doesn't happen again

I have tried different things

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
                             QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLabel,QMenu,QKeySequenceEdit)



class MyPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
     def triggerAction(self, action, checked=False):
        if action == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.OpenLinkInNewWindow:
            self.createWindow(
                QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserWindow
            )
        return super(MyPage, self).triggerAction(action, checked)



class MyWindow(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    currentLoadProgress = 0
    currentFile = ''
    pdf_count = 0

    def __init__(self,windows, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myPage = MyPage(self)
        self.setPage(self.myPage)
        self._windows = windows
        self._windows.append(self)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput("file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/default.html"))
        self.show()


    def createWindow(self, windows):
        if windows == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
            webview = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webview.show()
            return webview
        if windows == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.WebDialog:
            webview = MyWindow([])
            webview.show()
            return webview
        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windows)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = []
    a= MyWindow(windows)
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>URL Error</title>

</head>

<body>

<center style="padding-top:100px">

<h2>Invaid URL</h2>

<p>No URL passed in argument!</p>


</center>


<a href="#" onclick="return openPopup('1');">JS function window.open with Properties</a><br><br>


<script language="javascript">

function openPopup(obj)

{

try

{

if(obj=="1")

{

window.open('https://www.google.com','DevSearch','top=0,left=0,width=950,height=550,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); 

}
}  

catch(e)

{

alert("Script Error... Please Contact With Administrator ! ");

return false;

}

}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

When the link is clicked with window.open with properties it show open the link in new tab, everytime the link is clicked.

Comment: this solved one fourth of the problem. when new window is opened PyQt know the window is opened, and when window.close is pressed the window is still there but now when window.open is clicked new window opens....please try this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close